# Improved presentation and punctuation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Grid inside a grid. I want it to to avail maximum size irrespective of window size:

- Main_Grid  should be max width
- Grid_tool_bar should be max width

but in fact it is not and I am unable to find the reason. Here is code:

```
<Window x:Class="SocialNetworkingApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Background="White" WindowStyle="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" WindowState="Normal" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Border Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" >
        <Grid x:Name="Main_Grid" Background="White" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Name="Title_Bar" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ShowGridLines="True" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" MouseDown="Drag_Window" Background="#FF4FA2DA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="766" Height="31">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

[image]

Resolved by minimizing attributes

```
<Window x:Class="SocialNetworkingApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Background="White" WindowStyle="None"  WindowState="Normal" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Border Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" >
        <Grid x:Name="Main_Grid" Background="White" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Name="Title_Bar" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Background="#FF4FA2DA" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <Grid Name="Title_Bar" Grid.Row="0" ... Width="766" Height="31">
```

If you want it to autofit, do **not** specify a Width. Just remove that attribute.

Edit: Remove the `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` setters as well. At least for the outer grid.

Comment: I tried it that way too, it didnt work, now whole of child grid shrinked to about 5 pixels

Comment: See edit. Always try with minimal layout first. Only add what you really need.

Comment: i removed alignments, still nothing.

Comment: I Copy/Pasted your XAML and got it to auto-fill the width quite easily. Look for errors, they may block a refresh.

Comment: i had no errors. But i acted on ur advice, i minimized the attributes, and i have fixed it. alignments were causing troubles. I am using VS2012.